# How do you round floats conditionally?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query that is used by report generating software.

Part of this is querying for the hours needed to complete a project.  We record this a 2 decimal float so that we can estimate to the quarter hour.

However, if we are using it in our report and the hour we recorded is something like 8.00, I want to query it and format it so that 8.00 is just 8.  However any hours with something past the decimal, like 8.25, should remain as 8.25.  How can I make this work?

```
hours                     Queried Result
======    -> My Query ->  ==============
8.00                      8
8.25                      8.25
```

I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: How should `8.5` be returned?

Comment: 8.50 is fine.   It's all stored as `decimal(11,2)` types, so anything except the whole numbers can just be as is.

Comment: The question says it's float, not decimal. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REPLACE()` function to remove `.00`:

```
REPLACE(hours, '.00', '') AS hours
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a string and check the rightmost 2 characters and trim those if they are '00'.

```
 SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT REPLACE(Round(8.00), '.00', ' ');**

I will give more example so you can clear your Logic:

### MySQL ROUND() rounds a number specified as an argument up to a number specified as another argument.

Syntax:

**ROUND(N,[D]);**

Where **'N'** is rounded up to D decimal places.
and **'D'** is indicating up to how many decimal places N will be rounded.

Example 1:-

```
SELECT ROUND(4.43);
```

Output :-

```
 4
```

### The above MySQL statement will round the given number 4.43. No decimal places have been defined, so the default decimal value is 0.

Example 2:-

```
SELECT ROUND(-4.53);
```

Output:-

```
-5
```

### The above MySQL statement will round the given number -4.53. No decimal places have been defined, so the default decimal value is 0.